# Why array of uint8_t behave like this?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have got a function declared like this:

```
uint8_t* func()
{
    uint8_t arr[8] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    return arr;
}
```

But when I try to read this data from a function - casted to unsigned:

```
uint8_t* readedArray = func();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    cout << (unsigned int)readedArray[i] << endl; 
}
```

I'm not getting as a result

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

but something like this:

```
1
16
131
0
136
153
222
12
```

Why is it caused?

Comment: You are accessing the array after it no longer exists (it exists only inside of the function `func`). It's undefined behavior.

Comment: To make this work use auto func() { std::array<uint8_t,8> arr{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; return arr; }. "C" style arrays can't really be returned from functions very well. And strange as it may seem returning instances of local classes is defined behavior (C++ can be complicated like that see : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Comment: I'm idiot. Thank you guys!